# ios convert NSString into date?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a string containing:
`2013-10-29 18:50:18 +0000`

How can i convert this into a date, but keeping the same date format?

I've tried:

```
        NSString *str3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", time];

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:str3];
```

But `myDate` returns `(null)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not duplicate because i dont understand how to convert it into the same format

Comment: You have to make sure your string is coming in exactly like you are stating it is: 2013-10-29 12:10:00 AM

Comment: With standard formats like this you should consider using standard C library function like strptime_l and strftime_l.
You can find an example on the end of this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? He is asking about **this specific date format**, not generaly _How to convert date_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ
```

- `HH` for hours, because you clearly have 24-hour clock
- `ZZZ` for timezone, because you used `a` and that’s for AM/PM period

Full reference of [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Happy to help. I added link to full table of Unicode formatting patterns.

Comment: I think this page is much more understandably show the available formatting patterns:
http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Comment: @TussLászló It’s basically copy-pasted from Unicode page.

Comment: You are right, i don't inspected the full Unicode page. But for me that was way easier to understand.